# iOS 7 Background Location updates high accuracy, low battery usage with pausing disabled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, location, cllocationmanager

I'm working on an app which notifies the user of pre-defined locations as they enter or leave it. The span of a location can be as low as 50 meters, so it needs to be fairly accurate and regular. The location updates are currently sent to a server, which determines wether the user is within a location region and sends notifications accordingly.

Our problem is that the iOS 7 change the location pausing has become a major issue. The app is still open (in app switcher), but after 15 minutes no more location updates are received until the app is re-opened. But the user needs to be notified of all future locations they enter. Using the "setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically" method to disable pausing causes GPS to be enabled constantly regardless of the defined activity type.

I'm fairly certain I've almost exhausted all methods available to fulfil all requirements. Prior to iOS 7 our app worked great. The battery life was acceptable (I do understand it will never be perfect), on a daily charge cycle but we need to improve it somewhat.

Here's a quick run down on our solutions so far:

- Keep a local copy of locations and register them using CLLocationManager regions. Unfortunately we found the accuracy of this very bad and enter/exit methods were called too late to be viable
- A custom location model; initially using significant location updates, switching to standard location updates when the user moves x meters. But significant location updates are only given every 500 meters and every 5 minutes
- Similar to above, except use the accelerometer to enable location updates based on a number of steps. But the accelerometer data isn't available whilst in a background state
- Turn on location updates every 3 minutes from a finite running background task - this works but I'm not sure if every 3 minutes regardless of other circumstances would effect battery life too much
- Another idea, although not tested would be to rely on Passbook to send notifications. From experience it's more reliable. Of course this is a fairly big change and not something we have tested yet.

A classic example of what we're trying to achieve, in terms of accuracy and reliability is Moves. I use it constantly and it's always active and last a full day in terms of battery life.

Basically I'm asking if anyone has used any of my mentioned solutions or has any other working solutions or configurations?

I'm very much hoping that someone out their can influence one of my existing solutions or even provide a new, working solution because I'm not sure there's much else that can be done.

Thanks very much in advance to anyone reading this.

Answer (score 0):

For your Task (location every 50m) you need permanent GPS.
It makes no sense to disable an reenable every few minutes.

You either need to set `CLLocationAccuracyBest` or `accuracyBestForNavigation`.
But beware: accuracyBestForNavigation may enable acceleration Sensor, read the docu for `CLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`

So in your case I would use `CLLocationAccuracyBest`. (to avoid unneeded enabling of sensors)

Think if you need GPS in background, or let the user decide whether your app works permanetly or only in foreground.

At ios6, my app could run 8h permanent GPS recording. (If you have disabled 3rd party messaging service, and do not play all the time with the display.)

At ios7 this has not changed: I have now 8h of permanently  recording one fix per second, and have 41% of battery remaining. So your ios7 problem is not caused by GPS battery consumption.

Comment: I’m fairly certain that turning on location updates and leaving them on, but tweaking the configuration isn’t the solution I’m after. The only way for those configurations are designed for use is with a device currently charging.

My thoughts are that prior to iOS 6, the CLLocationAccuracyBest accuracy was optimised so that a user can get a full day charge out of it. But with the location pause configuration in iOS 7 (I’m aware it’s available 6+ but doesn’t seem as though it was in full effect), they’ve removed some or even all of this optimisation because battery life was vastly reduced.

Comment: If the "The span of a location can be as low as 50 meters, so" I can garuantee you, that there is no other soultion than to permanently leave the GPS on all the time. There is no 30% or 50% GPS. Either 0% or 100% GPS there is nothing inbetween. Network locationing via GSm cell Id will be about 1000m acuaracy, Network via Wlan locationing depends on the density of Wlan acces point that are in the Datatbase of Apple. Measure how many hours you can operate now with full GPS, and post here, I will measure too, and post it here as comment. Make sure you disable all social Apps and Messengers.

Comment: I measured now battery consumption of ios7 GPS. It is exactly as in iso5-6; I have 7:20h of recording every second one location with 51% battery remaining. So your problem is elsewhere, not caused by GPS.

Comment: After 11,5h battery went down to 7%, so the limit is a bit undeer 12h.

Comment: My measures prooves that your thoughts are not correct: "My thoughts are that prior to iOS 6, the CLLocationAccuracyBest accuracy was optimised". You have another problem, not based on Location service, maybe the communication part uses now more battery.